# Is it possible in Alfresco avoid the resource url random generated?

Tags: caching, alfresco

I understand that in production it is a good practice to use random generated filename to force the browser to download the file and not use cache (cache busting).

For example Alfresco generate files like this:

*http://localhost:8080/share/res/js/surf/3f1b42d3f51529dabe2af76fecf9ebcd.js*

And If I make a change in my libraries it will change the URL.

My question: It is possible to avoid this behavior in development?

I will like a path like:

*http://localhost:8080/share/res/js/surf/surf.js*

The advantage of that is that I can put break points, make changes in the code and then reload the page.

Right now I have to each time I reload the page, I have to find one more time  the part of the code I am working on and then putting the breakpoint reload one more time.

Comment: [Turn on share client-debugging](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/dev-extensions-share-tutorials-debugging.html)?

Comment: I already have : <client-debug>true</client-debug> in share-config-custom. I think the only difference is the compression of the files